# Open source video editing software for linux?

Tags: linux, open-source, video, video-editing

I'd like to find a good solid video editing software for Linux, preferably open-source.

I've recently tried Cinelerra and Kdenlive, however kdenlive crashed on me a trifle too often for my liking. Cinelerra seems to have a bit of a learning curve behind it, as I was unsuccessful at importing a single clip (didn't seem to auto detect the format correctly).

I'm a big Blender user, but the built in VSE is not quite enough for me.

Are there any solid GIMP/Blender equivalent programs for video editing?

---

*I haven't tried Openshot in a while, but it was very unstable last time I tried it. If it's gotten better I might have to give it another go.*

Comment: KDEnlive is far less crashy now (Jan 2017). It's the best of the bunch if you just want to be able to wade in and not learn a new interface IMO. I tried [Lightworks](https://www.lwks.com/) recently, it seems good but the interface was too kooky for me.

Comment: @pbhj Good to know, thanks; I'll give it a whirl next time I have something to edit. I don't mind learning some interfaces, but lightworks looks a bit proprietary for my taste..

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/best-video-editing-software-linux/

Comment: Note: [phuclv's comment](itsfoss.com/best-video-editing-software-linux) suggests `kdenlive` by a voting sample size of **4,600**.  It was probably written around [Dec. 19, 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170801000000*/https://itsfoss.com/best-video-editing-software-linux/).  Many more people voted than on the direct answers to this question.  So I'm gonna go with `kdenlive`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently came across [Shotcut](http://shotcut.org). It runs on Linux and it is based on the same backend as OpenShot: the MLT toolkit. It is opensource and crossplatform.

[image]

Comment: There site is down. "Your website is ready.
This site has been successfully created and is ready for content to be added. Replace this default page with your own index page." Do you think they will have it up soon or are they not very supported?

Comment: @Daniel Try here instead: http://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/Shotcut/WebHome

Comment: @Daniel I misstyped the link. It is http://shotcut.org not .com

Comment: What Are your experiences with this? Currently I have little more then a link and a screenshot. Could you make this more of a recommendation?

Comment: I tried a lot of open source video editors, but this is the best and it doesn't crash (yeah, it doesn't!!) in Windows.

Answer (score 8):

I rarely do video editing, but in the past used **[OpenShot](http://www.openshot.org/)**. The "learning curve" is pretty low (compared to *Cinerella*), and it nicely integrates with *[Blender](http://www.blender.org/)* and other tools.

[image: OpenShot Screenshot]
<sup>*OpenShot* screenshot (source: [OpenShot](http://www.openshot.org/screenshots/); click image for larger variant – and the link for more screenshots)</sup>

Other than your experience, *OpenShot* never crashed on me. It ran smooth and stable, exported fine, editing was a breeze. I have to admit, my last use of it was back in January/February 2014 – but I'd rather expect it to have improved since then ;)

Comment: I'll give it another shot then :) (no pun intended :P)

Comment: Yepp: Open your installer and give it a Shot :D

Comment: I must be very good at this.. I managed to lock it up, however it felt a lot more stable and less buggy than it did before (in the past the preview window was subject to all kinds of drawing bugs, but not anymore). Could be a solution, but I'll try out the others first.

Comment: Openshot 1.4.3 hasn't been updated in a while (the author it's working on version 2.0) and for the time I used it it seemed very stable.

Comment: While talking about Blender, it's good to notice that Blender itself has a built-in video editor!

Comment: @Pithikos Indeed, I even noted it in the question ;)

Comment: OpenShot handles rotations VERY poorly. I tried rotating a 16:9 video so it sits upright in the right half of the screen but it for some reason insists on the 16:9 aspect ratio rather than changing it to 9:16 for the subclip after rotating. This leads to it cutting off the left and right (now top and bottom) edges of the video =/

Comment: I've meanwhile switched to [Shotcut](https://www.shotcut.org/). Works smoother for me, and produces "clearer" results.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but [flowblade](https://jliljebl.github.io/flowblade/) looks really promising!

It advertises advanced compositing and animation features and has a polished-looking UI

[image: product photo]

Answer (score -2):

c&p from https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11482/7170

How about [PiTiVi](http://pitivi.org)?
It's a Free Software video editor based on GStreamer. It's written in Python and should run on [windows](http://wiki.pitivi.org/wiki/PiTiVi_on_Windows), although I wouldn't expect it to run as well there.

Have a look at [the manual](http://pitivi.org/manual/) to see whether it fits your needs.
[image: PiTiVi main window]

oh, they also have a [fundraiser running](http://fundraiser.pitivi.org/).

Comment: "should run on windows": rather not a criterium, as the OP explicitly asked "for Linux". But mentioning GStreamer already points to its running on Linux; apart from that, it's one of the better known video editors for Linux even. So instead of "simply c&p" (duplicating content), you should at least edit your answer to match the question :)

Comment: Looks very nice, however it failed to import a clip, throwing a python traceback and a type error. I'll keep messing with it though..