# Easy video editor for beginner to make tutorial video

Tags: gratis, open-source, video, video-editing

I want to make a tutorial video. I'm a beginner, and am giving up with some video editors in Linux. There's a bug in Avidemux and OpenShot which got some recommendations, and I have no clue how to use Blender; it's just way too complex.

I want to make tutorial video that allows me to create some texts and objects. For example, I want to have a button in my video, so I want to give a circle for that button, and text explanation for that action.

What software I can use to easily make that text and object?

I have Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu, both 64bit with 4GB RAM.

Free / Open-Source software are preferable.  Paid software will be considered (unless it has trial version).

I don't care if it runs under Windows or Linux, because I have both.

Any recommendation will be appreciated.

Comment: You might wish to check [these (currently 12) related questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-editing?sort=frequent), e.g. [Open source video editing software for linux?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14656/185) and [Easy-to-learn video editor for Windows?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/16725/185)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ezVid](http://www.ezvid.com/), its a simple movie editor that should be able to help you with what you are trying to achieve.

For any bigger projects, or if you are attempting to build your skill-set, I would definitely start working through some blender tutorials, and of course, blender can do what you want to create.

Comment: I just tried ezVid. It's great simple video editor, easy to use. But, it's just provide basic tools. There is no tool that I can use to draw animated circle and inline text explanation. :( Great software by the way.