# Windows video editing software to add color rectangles to particular frames

Tags: windows, video-editing

I am looking for a software that allows one to view each video frame, delete or add or erase undesired figures or objects on it, or overlay any other object say color filled rectangle, etc. and then save the video again.

Requirements:

- Works on Windows
- Frame-by-frame view
- Can add rectangles where I want and choose their color

Comment: [Lightworks](http://www.lwks.com/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Freeware video editing software](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11433/freeware-video-editing-software)

Comment: Voting to leave open. This question has specific requirements about how to handle individual frames, the suggested duplicate has not. @Anu it helps if you add more info. Supported formats? Price?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not looking at an "editing" program, you are looking for a "composite program". (An editing program is to assemble video sequences one after another. A compositing program is to assemble elements inside sequences one on top another)

Frame by frame... probably any compositing program can do that but that is too primitive. Now you can use tracking motion.

- Take a look at [HitFilm Express](https://hitfilm.com/express), that is free, and has 3D tracking. You can inclusive select a pimples on a person's face, and the program tracks it on a series of frames, and you can put something over there.
- You can use [Blender](https://www.blender.org/), that also has motion tracking. Also free.
- [After Effects](https://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html) is a compositing program too but this costs some bucks. You can use a monthly subscription. (But you can do that in HitFilm for free)
- If you require a more advanced frame by frame retouching use [Photoshop](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html) itself.
- [Photo Paint](http://www.coreldraw.com/en/product/graphic-design-software/) also can edit video.
- And [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) with a plugin GAP

The problem with this last 3 is that you are not editing a "video" but a ton of layers, one per frame, so you need to keep your sequences short.

Answer (score 0):

[Magix Movie Edit](http://www.magix.com/int/movie-edit-pro/detail/functions/), commercial

- runs on Windows Vista or later
- can view single frames
- can overlay unwanted elements with e.g. a rectangle
- cannot (AFAIK) erase undesired figures automatically, but since you said "*or*", this is then optional
- can save the video again